# Get Free Memory Available

Tags: powershell, memory

I have to get by PowerShell command the ammount of free memory size (the same that I see in the Performance Monitor GUI):

[image]

I have searched on each parameter seen on the following command output:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem | fl *free*
```

but I haven't found anything useful.
Could you help me please?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350392/here-is-x-part-of-any-program-ever-how-do-i-get-change-this-in-powershell/

Comment: check the `Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Memory` class

Comment: I have solve the problem with this code: gwmi Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Memory |% {($_.FreeAndZeroPageListBytes|Measure-Object -sum).sum/1024/1024}

Answer (score 1):

The [`Win32_OperatingSystem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394239.aspx) class provides a global view on the free memory. As [Avshalom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47571004/powershell-get-free-memory-available#comment82099570_47571004) already pointed out you need to query a different WMI class ([`Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Memory`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/aa394314(v=vs.80))), since you're looking for a particular portion of the total free memory.

Subtract the two standby cache sizes from the available bytes to get the desired value:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Memory | ForEach-Object {
    $_.AvailableBytes - ($_.StandbyCacheNormalPriorityBytes + $_.StandbyCacheReserveBytes)
}
```

Divide the result by `1MB` to get the value in megabytes instead of bytes.